# Differential equation $E[X_t] = b + log(a) \int_{0}^{t} E[X_s]ds$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following equation?
$$E[X_t] = b + log(a) \int_{0}^{t} E[X_s]ds$$

I am not sure, how to start. Is there a special trick, how to solve ODE's like this?

Comment: you can differentiate both side and use the fundamental theorem of calculus for the right side ...then you get a first ode

Answer (score 1):

Write $E[X_t]=f(t)$. Then your equation in differential form writes
$$
\frac d{dt} f(t) = \log(a)f(t),\ t>0,\quad f(0)=b.
$$
A solution is $f(t)=ba^t$. You can define the deterministic stochastic process $X_t=ba^t$ with probability $1$, then $f(t):=E[X_t]=ba^t$ solves your equation.

Comment: Thank you very much! Which technique did you use to solve the ODE?

Comment: Just guessed using known differentiation rules, as the ODE suggests an exponential function.

Comment: Oh, I know my mistake now, I thougt, I need to find an antiderivative for log(t), but it is log(a) and therefore log(a)t. Thanks!